# array of objects in cocos2d with touching functionality

Tags: xcode, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a simple game where fruits will fall from the top and the user collects them by clicking.
My problem is for example the apple that falls disappears when it is clicked on, so there is only 1 apple to be collected so far. I want to make some kind of an array to store like 5 apples and they should fall at random speed and random positions. And then when the last one is collected it should disappear.

This is what I am trying now and it doesnt seem to work:
This is where the CCSprite Apple is created:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"];
        [self addChild:Apple];
        int positionX = arc4random()%450;
        [Apple setPosition:ccp(positionX, 768)];
    }
```

and this for the movement from top to bottom:

```
-(void) callEveryFrame:(ccTime)dt
{
    Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, Apple.position.y -300*dt);
    if (Apple.position.y < -100+64)
    {
        int positionX = arc4random()%1004;
        [Apple setPosition:ccp(positionX, 768)];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Edited solution adding random position and speed.
Note 2: New edition adding touches detection.

With a single variable to store five CCSprites?. 
Finally you will only have the last CCSprite in that variable.

You need to store CCSprite(s) in a CCArray (or NSMutableArray)

Try this in your header file .h:

```
@interface xyz : CCLayer {
        CCArray *appleArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCArray *appleArray;
```

In your implementation file .m:

```
@synthesize appleArray;

- (id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        self.touchEnabled = YES;

        // Inicialize CCArray
        self.appleArray = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            CCSprite *Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"];
            [self addChild:Apple];

            int positionX = arc4random()%450;
            int positionY = 768 + arc4random()%1000;
            // Store speed 
            float speed = 150 + arc4random()%400;
            Apple.tag = speed;
            [Apple setPosition:ccp(positionX, positionY)];

            // Add CCSprite into CCArray
            [appleArray addObject:Apple];
        }

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        CCSprite *Apple = ((CCSprite *)[appleArray objectAtIndex:i]);

        if (Apple.position.y > -250) {
            Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, Apple.position.y - (Apple.tag*dt));
        }
    }
}

- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    for (CCSprite *Apple in self.appleArray)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(Apple.boundingBox, location))
        {
            Apple.visible = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! It is getting there but that is not what I actually wanted. What I meant was: say when the game starts there should be only 5 apples and the apples need to fall one at a time and each one should have a random speed. Say Apple1 falls then Apple2 etc.. and then when Apple 5 falls it should stop throwing anymore apples.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Edit and changed solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hmm I thought this is what I wanted but the apples still pretty much fall in a couple of seconds.. Is there a way to make a apple fall then wait for say 2-3 seconds then fall another and so on?

Comment: changing this line: int positionY = (1000 + i) + arc4random()%1000;

Comment: Thanks man! Now my touch doesnt work on all of the apples, it only works on 1 apple. Is there maybe something I need to change in my touch code?

- (BOOL) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    return YES;
}

Comment: -(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self ccTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    
    float distanceApple = powf(self.Apple.position.x - location.x, 2) + powf(self.Apple.position.y - location.y, 2);
    distanceApple = sqrtf(distanceApple);
    
    if(distanceApple <=35)
    {   
        Apple.visible = false;
    }
}

Comment: In ccTouchesBegan, you need another loop for to check the five Apples: <br/>for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   CCSprite *Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"]; // Your code
    }

Comment: do you mean:     float distanceApple = powf(self.Apple.position.x - location.x, 2) + powf(self.Apple.position.y - location.y, 2);
    distanceApple = sqrtf(distanceApple);
    //If the (place touched) radius of the object is less than or equal to 25 then start the operation
    if(distanceApple <=35)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"];
            Apple.visible = false;
        }
    }

Comment: I say something like this: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"];  float distanceApple = powf(self.Apple.position.x - location.x, 2) + powf(self.Apple.position.y - location.y, 2); distanceApple = sqrtf(distanceApple); //If the (place touched) radius of the object is less than or equal to 25 then start the operation if(distanceApple <=35) {  Apple.visible = false;  }  }

Comment: Still not working, tried re arranging but still no luck, can you maybe edit the code on the top so I can see clearly?

Comment: Done!. Please update the original question to make it clear that this solution is an expanded response.

Comment: I edited the question, why cant I upvote your question? it says 15 reputation required